# Change textbox language

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello I have several textboxes one of them has to be set to Russian input, if I change the language as shown below it changes the default language on my machine to Russian. I would like it to revert back to the machines default language when I go onto any of the other textboxs or select the button and not alter to Russian on my machine.

```
<TextBox></TextBox>
<TextBox></TextBox>
<TextBox InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage="ru"></TextBox>
<TextBox></TextBox>
<Button />
```

Answer (score 0):

change the input language to "ru-RU"